# Use an existing queue with Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to write a Java Spring Boot application using AMQP to talk to a RabbitMQ server. I have to use existing queues and exchanges and do not have the rights to declare them myself (nor do I want to). The problem is that I cannot keep the Spring Integrations from trying to declare the queue in RabbitMQ, which returns an error.

Here's a screenshot of the message sent from Wireshark:

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7s5W.png)

My main class is annotated with the @EnableBindings(Sink.class) annotation.

Here's the relevant part of my application.properties:

> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=********************.instana.test
>       spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bind-queue=false
>       spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.queue-name-group-only=true
>       spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.declare-exchange=false
>       spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.durable-subscription=false
>       spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.exclusive=true

Note: I do NOT want to use the RabbitMQ specific implementations of Spring, but rather the Spring cloud stream solutions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to prevent the attempt to declare the queue; but you can simply ignore the error.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/184